# Downside of "Override software rendering" Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, chromium, vivaldi

Why is this an experimental feature? What are the potential downsides of enabling?

---

chrome://flags#ignore-gpu-blacklist

> **Override software rendering list** Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
>
> Overrides the built-in software rendering list and enables GPU-acceleration on unsupported system configurations.

Enabling fixed video playback issues (YouTube & Twitter) on Chromium/Vivaldi.

Using Macbook Pro, OSX 10.9.5. Would updating fix issues?